# TextMate 2 “Go To Symbol” not working for PHP

Tags: macos, php, textmate-2

I’m running TextMate 2.0-alpha.9419 and experiencing this issue: the editor doesn’t see my method definitions within a class, and won’t let me jump to them via “Go To Symbol”. The only method that TM does recognise is `__construct` which is hardly useful enough.

[image]

I do have the PHP bundle installed.

Is this just something that is missing from the bundle/TM alpha build, or is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to updated the PHP bundle to add user-defined methods to the symbol list.

Goto "Bundles" => "Edit Bundles"

[image]

Select the PHP Bundle & create a new Bundle Setting

- ( <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> ) => select "Setting"

[image]

Enter a name, "entity.name.function.php" as Scope Selector, and enter the following setting

```bash
{ showInSymbolList = 1; }
```

[image]

Save setting ( <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> ) and close Bundle Editor.

- You may need to restart TextMate.app and/or clear cache

```bash
$ rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Cache/*
```

You should now have named functions in your symbol list

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I’m puzzled though as to why this isn’t configured by default.

Comment: This bundle _is_ configured by default. Remember TM2 is in active development -- so many things will work, then break, then work again. I imagine the author(s) of the PHP bundle are waiting for a beta version before refactoring code.